# How to convert this powershell script to bin/sh script?

Tags: linux, powershell, sh

How to convert this script:

```
NET USE \\65.161.3.129\someFolder\test /u:somedomain\user myPassword123!
robocopy . \\65.161.3.129\someFolder\test /s
NET USE \\65.161.3.129\someFolder\test /d
```

or with parameter:

```
Param($mypath)
NET USE $mypath /u:somedomain\user myPassword123!
robocopy . $mypath /s
NET USE $mypath /d
```

How to make similar script that works in linux `/bin/sh`?
I want to copy files to some network location (windows shared folder). There is no scp on windows server and i cannot install anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux, you'll need the following (verified on Ubuntu 18.04, albeit not with a Windows *domain* account):

- Prerequisite: The `cifsutil` package must be installed, which the script below ensures (it calls `sudo apt-get install cifs-utils` on demand).
- Choose a (temporary) mount point (a local directory through which the share's files will be accessible).
- Use the `mount.cifs` utility to mount your share, and `umount` to unmount (remove) it later.
- Use `cp -R` to copy a directory hierarchy.

Note:

- `sudo` (administrative) privileges are required; the script will prompt *once* for a password, which is normally cached for a few minutes.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# The SMB file-share path given as an argument.
local mypath=$1 

# Choose a (temporary) mount-point dir.
local mountpoint="/tmp/mp_$$"

# Prerequisite:
# Make sure that cifs-utils are installed.
which mount.cifs >/dev/null || sudo apt-get install cifs-utils || exit

# Create the (temporary) mount-point dir.
sudo mkdir -p "$mountpoint" || exit

# Mount the CIFS (SMB) share:
# CAVEAT: OBVIOUSLY, HARD-CODING A PASSWORD IS A SECURITY RISK.
sudo mount.cifs -o user= "user=user,pass=myPassword123!,domain=somedomain" "$mypath" "$mountpoint" || exit

# Perform the copy operation
# Remove the `echo` to actually perform copying.
echo cp -R . "$mountpoint/"

# Unmount the share.
sudo umount "$mountpoint" || exit

# Remove the mount-point dir., if desired
sudo rmdir "$mountpoint"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're on a linux flavour, the `curl` utility can handle SMB (i.e. `\\machine\share`) paths. Example:

`curl -u "domain\username:passwd" smb://server.example.com/share/file.txt`

See https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html

Comment: That's definitely good to know, but it looks like it's limited to handing a single file whose full name is known in advance, so it's not practical to use it to copy an entire directory hierarchy, as requested by the OP. Aside from that, I would also expect it to work on macOS (and other Unix flavors). (In my experiments (on both Linux and macOS) I kept running into a `Connection reset by peer` errors, but I may be doing something wrong.)